# I would like to set up a notification trigger when new data is added to a remote server. What is the best approach?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm a little lost and need some guidance on how to approach this feature I'd like to add.

Many operations I use require retrieving data from a remote server. My goal is to be able to receive an email notification if new data has been added to the remote server.

I thought about creating a stored procedure that uses "openquery" and compare data to a local table with a conditional statement that will send out an email if there are differences. Then scheduling a job that will execute this stored procedure frequently. But this does not feel elegant at all...

Comment: Do you have the ability to make modifications to the database on the remote server?   Like adding a trigger?

Comment: I do not. Basically a read-only.

Comment: Maybe CDC is useful; I don't really know that much about it.  Otherwise, I'd go with the job > openquery approach that you already mentioned.   It's fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, all depends on the permissions.

> 1. If I was the owner of the system

Find out which job is adding data to the system. Modify the process (ETL/ SQL job etc.) to send you an email. (**best way**)

> 2. If you have create permissions on the remote system

Create an after insert [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms189799.aspx), see the first example here. Refer to this [link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3964/send-email-when-certain-data-is-being-inserted-in-ms-sql-server) as well. (**2nd best way**)

> 3. If you have just permissions to create linked server

Whatever you wrote/ you can bring the data from the server (just the primary keys from the table) and keep on checking that by creating a job for new primary keys if any by copying the data to local.

How to choose between these two: depends on the size of data. Second method mentioned in point 3 will work even without a linked server.

But you will have to run this again and again, I can't think of any other way. Set up a SQL job/ ETL to do this for you.

Comment: It sounds like option 3 is what I'll have to do, which confirms my original plan. I do not have any permissions on the remote system. All I've been doing is pulling the remote data into my server and executing queries that way.